# Data Grip - how do I perform a simple SQL formatting (the same way ctrl+shift+F does in DBeaver)?

Tags: sql, presto, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I'm using Data Grip and writing queries for use with Presto. How can I get Data Grip to format my queries so they will be neat and easy to read?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

`Ctrl/Cmd+Alt+L` formats your code.

`Settings | Editor | Code Style | SQL` to adjust.

Comment: Hi @moscas I've tried that and it does absolutely nothing! It will say "No lines changed: content is already properly formatted" even when the code is not formatted! any ideas?

Comment: @GiladZa789 That means that your code is formatted according to defined code style. You need to set up code style to match you expectations

Comment: @kassak I've set up code style, and yet nothing happens. I can write a super-long line and then press Ctrl+Alt+L and it won't even wrap the text. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, are you editing the SQL file or a console? What dialect do you use? A screencast will be useful here

Comment: Hi @moscas, I've added two screenshots, hope that's helpful. I'm writing in Presto which should be general SQL. Appreciate your help here.

Comment: Got it! The formatter doesn't wok for the dialects which are not supported. It will be fixed in 2020.3

Comment: Mac: Cmd + Option + L

Answer (score 5):

For macOS:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>